# What is the fastest way to download large files from S3 to EC2 in same region?

Tags: file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, download

I want to download large files from s3 to ec2 instances for file manipulation.  What would be the fastest and most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use VPC endpoints https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest and most efficient"? Have you tried a method and found it to be not fast/efficient? Can you provide any examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried AWS CLI and downloaded a 1GB file in about 48 Seconds.  The S3 and EC2 were in the same region.  I just wanted to know if there is a faster way because every second counts for me in this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has an `aws s3 cp` command to download files, and an `aws s3 sync` command to synchronize the content between a local directory and S3 (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what everyone recommends.

Comment: If you have *many* small files, you might want to investigate downloading in parallel to fully utilize available bandwidth. But if they are big files, it won't help as much due to less overhead.

Comment: Thank you. It works 10x times faster, than use `wget`

Answer (score 1):

One technique to achieve speed is to divide the problem into smaller problems, execute the smaller problems in parallel, and then assemble the results.  In this case I believe that a utility can be written in which there are a number of workers each of which is responsible for downloading a portion of the file from S3 to EBS/EFS using ranged gets.  The workers would all run in parallel.  After all the pieces have been downloaded then they can be combined into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like [s5cmd](https://github.com/peak/s5cmd) is significantly *faster* for downloading objects than aws-cli (golang vs python makes a big difference). Their github README has some performance results that show ~10x speed difference.

It can be used like:
`s5cmd cp s3://bucketname/object.txt localobject.txt`